# How to build for XP in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio-2017

I tried to follow [Configuring Programs for Windows XP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp), but I have no `General` option under `Configuration Properties`. I installed `Desktop development with C++` and `Windows XP support for C++`.

[image]

Comment: The project is in C#

Comment: Because I'm beginner and I always had problems with visualc++ dll's when building python projects for XP. So, it's that simple, just to install .net 3.5 and use it in my project

Comment: I can't find .net 3.5 sdk or 4.03 which is how I read latest supported on XP. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-xp Do I need sdk or runtime for vs? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. In VS 2017 I used .net4 which is the lowest version you can use in VS2017 by default. Then I installed .net4 in WinXp from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718 and the app compiled in x64 Win10 in VS2017 and succesfuly run in 32bit WinXP SP3.

Comment: No need to delete them. Your comments helped me ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution how to compile C# project in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 for Windows XP. In VS2017 go to Solution Explorer and right click on your project. Go to properties and under Application menu choose `.NET Framework 4` under `Target framework`. This is the lowest version you can select in VS2017 installed by default.

I thought that the latest .NET framework working on XP was 3.5. However, I was wrong. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-xp) at Microsoft docs it says:

> .NET Framework 4.0.3 The .NET Framework 4.0.3 is the latest supported
>   .NET Framework version on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. The .NET
>   Framework 4.0.3 requires that the .NET Framework 4 is installed first.
>   Both of these .NET Framework versions are no longer supported by
>   Microsoft.
>
> .NET Framework 4 You can install the .NET Framework 4 on Windows XP.
>   It's no longer supported by Microsoft.

I compiled the project with .NET 4 framework and it didn't work by default on XP. It complained abount not being a valid application without offering to install newer .NET4.

After that I googled `.net4 for xp` and found a file `dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe` [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718). Installed it on XP machine and my project exe file worked on 32-bit XP SP3 while being compiled on Win10 VS2017 64-bit.